# Select a record in Django: filtering foreign key using a query set

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have three (relevant) classes: groups (Group A, Group B, etc), topics (topics of discussion), and GroupMember (a list that links users to groups). Now, each topic is linked to one or more groups in which it will be posted. But, at the same time, users can subscribe to a topic (subscriptions field). See below the outline:

```
class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(User, through='GroupMember')

class Topic(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    groups = models.ManyToManyField(Group, related_name='topics')
    subscriptions = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='subscribed_to')

class GroupMember(models.Model):
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    start = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    end = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
```

Now I would like to select a topic, and then get a list with all the people who are part of that group. I tried this:

```
topic = Topic.objects.get(1)
members = GroupMember.objects.filter(group=topic.groups)
```

But this yields this error:

```
int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'ManyRelatedManager'
```

So my question is: is there a way to query GroupMembers by selecting a group, based on a queryset (which is what topic.groups is I guess), instead of an integer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should work:

```
topic = Topic.objects.get(1)
members = GroupMember.objects.filter(group__in = topic.groups.all())
```

Can refer the django's documentation on `in` here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#in

Comment: Thanks; I tried that but I then get: 
'ManyRelatedManager' object is not iterable

Comment: @user we need to call `all` to get an iterable from `ManyRelatedManager `

Comment: Superb, that's it!! Thanks!